# How to create a custom ubuntu cd?

Tags: custom-distributions, livedvd, custom-installer

I am a developer and use ubuntu. I want to create a live cd which has te IDE and SDK tools I use for develpment and also I want to run a pre installed git client with a repository configured. Also want to give te option to install ubuntu with all this preset software and code repository.

Comment: @Terrance There are 25 other answers to that question which is indeed stuck with an obselete answer about Ubuntu  Builder. For example, Ubuntu Customization Kit in the Ubuntu Software Center is still available for all currently supported Ubuntu releases.

Comment: @Terrance If you ever see one of my answers that is obselete, comment below the answer and I will either update it, rewrite it completely or delete it entirely.

Comment: @Terrance the second answer, by Rinzwind, while originally for 11.X, works fine for 14.04. It's not outdated.

Comment: @muru I have removed all my other comments as yes, you are correct. But I for one, and I can't vouch for everybody, but I am sure that there are people like me, that sometimes want to just try the first answer they see and not waste their time searching for the answers.  I understand that there is a good answer, and I stumbled across that one too the other day as I needed the same thing, but seeing that the largest answer on that page was outdated, I skipped over it.